# What are these three dots next to the gnome-shell extensions?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

After upgrading vom 19.10 to 20.04 I have a three-dot-icon in the list of my gnome-extensions:

[image]

Both left and right click have no effect and I cannot drag & drop it. What is it and do I want to get rid of it?

I'm referring to extensions because I assume all icons and their menus in the upper right corner represent extensions. Maybe that's wrong...

Comment: could you add in your question which is the list of gnome-shell-extensions that you have in your system?

Comment: seems this is related https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/issues/232

Comment: Pressing Alt + F2 and r makes it disappear. This commad restarts the Gnome shell. For more details see https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/issues/232#issuecomment-688773404. I'm also having this but don't know what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Steam?

I think the 3dots is what kstatusnotify plugin uses when there is no appindicator image provided.

Steam is the most popular app I know that has this behavior.